# How to get data from json file stored in Azure blob storage in react

Tags: reactjs, json, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm new to react and azure i want to store a json file on azure blob storage and get the data of that json file into react js

I don't know where to start can someone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To store Json file in Azure blob storage,** please try the following:

- Create a container using below cmdlet

```cs
azcopy make 'https://<storage-account-name>.<blob or dfs>.core.windows.net/<container-name>'
```

- To Upload a file, make use of below cmdlet

```cs
azcopy copy '<local-file-path>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.<blob or dfs>.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-name>'
```

You can also upload a file by using a wildcard symbol (*) anywhere in the file path or file name as `C:\my*\*.txt`.

- To Upload a specific files, make use of below cmdlet

```cs
azcopy copy '<local-directory-path>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.<blob or dfs>.core.windows.net/<container-name>' --include-path <semicolon-separated-file-list>
```

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Upload files to Azure Blob storage by using AzCopy v10 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json).
[node.js - Store json object to Azure blob storage - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324386/store-json-object-to-azure-blob-storage).

**To Get data of Json file into React js,** please try the following:

- Enable CORS for your Resource through Azure portal.
- Try accessing the blob by using below sample snippet:

```js
export function getJsonData<T = any>(url: string): Promise<T> {
return fetch(url, {
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json'
}
})
.then(response => {
return response.json();
})
.catch(error => {
return Promise.reject(error);
});}
```

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[reactjs - Get json file data which stored in Azure blob storage in React - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031820/get-json-file-data-which-stored-in-azure-blob-storage-in-react).